# iOS screen mirroring via USB to a Windows PC?

Tags: ios, screen, airplay, mirroring

I want to mirror the screen of an iOS device to a a Windows PC. I only found solutions which either use a VGA-adapter or AirPlay. Because AirPlay uses WiFi I seek for a more stable and independent solution. I stumbled on iTools but it seems it isn't developed anymore. It used a USB connection for showing the screen.

The only things which would suit my needs are either using a VGA/HDMI-adapter or using iOS 8 with Ad-Hoc WiFi and AirPlay. But then I would adapters for Lightning and Dock-Connector. On the other side it won't work for iOS 7 if I use the AirPlay method.

So is there any software which can mirror the screen via USB onto a Windows PC?

Comment: USB cable do not have the capability for screen display.

Comment: @Buscar웃: For what are the VGA/HDMI-Adapter used then?

Comment: HDMI might look like USB but it is not.

Comment: I still don't get what you mean. This is an adapter which should convert to a video signal (VGA, HDMI). Because it's an official adapter there should be a video output.

Comment: That is correct, but what dos that has to do with USB ? your question.

Comment: As developer you can connect your device via USB with your Mac. With iOS 8 and the latest Mac OS X you can mirror your device via USB. I'm seeking for a solution which also can do this but on PC and perhaps iOS 7.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a Mac you can try Quicktime Player. Start a new video recording, and select the connected iPhone as your video source and audio source.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Can you please provide more details on how to do this?

Comment: Does this also work on Windows?

Comment: 1. open quicktime 2. choose "new movie recording" 3. next to the big red "record button" there's a small downwards arrow, where you can select your iPhone, if it is connected via usb needs a lightning connector on the idevice, and at least yosemite

Comment: Yeah but that only works on MacOS, not windows

Answer (score 4):

The HDMI or VGA adapter that can be purchased from Apple allows mirroring to an external monitor, projector or other display that allows video **IN**.  Does your PC allow video in via HDMI?  (I'm not aware of any that do, most are video **OUT**)  There is a 3rd party application called [Duet](http://www.duetdisplay.com) that allows your iOS device to be used as an external or second monitor via USB but I think that is the opposite of what you are trying to accomplish based on your question.  The screenshot shows Duet for Mac but there is a PC version as well.

From the Apple documentation regarding cable:

> Use the Lightning to VGA Adapter with your iPad with Retina display, iPad mini, iPhone 5, and iPod touch (5th generation) with Lightning connector. The Lightning to VGA Adapter supports mirroring of what is displayed on your device screen including apps, presentations, websites, slideshows, and more — **to** your VGA-equipped TV, display, projector or other compatible display in up to 1080p HD.
>   It also **outputs video content** - movies, TV shows, captured video- to your big screen in up to 1080p HD. Simply attach your Lightning to VGA Adapter to the Lightning connector on your device and then to your TV or projector via a VGA cable (sold separately).

[Apple Store Link](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD825AM/A/lightning-to-vga-adapter?fnode=acf409b92d7ece95ca7b38a27e56e6da3f0106bebcb13dd8a4826c5362056d09fdc8723c566c3045fb326a7ad477d958fa3c1f5f91169e2b7df3564052e807945d49f91850b0bc1520fe1f6eadce500711603a05b6ea7f0ccc4de1015746260fec862a73019a3a4f996808c8323d0237)

Duet:
[image: Duet dialog]

UPDATE:  This may or may not be useful, but [this article](http://www.apowersoft.com/display-ipad-on-computer.html) mentions a method that may suit your needs.  From the article:

> Apowersoft Phone Manager
>   It is completely compatible with iOS and Android operation system. **To learn how to display iPad on computer**, get started with the following steps.
>   *Download this tool and connect iPad to computer **through USB cable.***

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to look for something like this that can capture the video from another device.

https://www.startech.com/AV/Converters/Video/usb-3-0-video-capture-device-hdmi-dvi-vga~USB3HDCAP

And then just get an adapter based on the type of input you are using. For example, if you decide to use VGA:

[https://www.amazon.com/Apple-MD825AM-Lightning-Adapter-iPhones/dp/B015ZRJ8NW/ref=pd_sim_147_3?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=1DFC75WB2PTKH34QQKCP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015ZRJ8NW).